# Perl creating a pipe and fork a sub-process

Tags: perl, subroutine

All im trying to do here is:

1. Create a pipe
2. Fork a sub-process
3. Parent gets a message from the user, sends it to the child
4. Child gets the message, prints it to the screen
5. Repeat until user doesn't enter a message

This is what I got now so far: I still need to implement a loop to repeat until user doesn't enter a message.

```
    #!perl -w
    use strict

    pipe(PIPE_READ, PIPE_WRITE);
    autoflush PIPE_WRITE 1;
    my $pid = fork();
    if ($pid) {
      &write_pipe ($pid);
      waitpid($pid,0);
    } 
    elsif (defined $pid) {
      &read_pipe;
    }
    else {
      die "cannot fork: $!";
    }

    sub write_pipe {
        print "pid $$ \n";
        print "Enter message: ";
        sleep 1;
        my $usr_msg = <>;
        print "Parent pid = $$  message = $usr_msg";
        print PIPE_WRITE "$usr_msg\n";
        close(PIPE_WRITE)
        close(PIPE_READ);
    }

    sub read_pipe {
        print "child pid = $pid";
        my $msg_read = <PIPE_READ>;
        close(PIPE_WRITE);
        print "received from pipe $msg_read";
    }
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Im not sure how to make it repeat until user doesnt enter a message! please help :(

Comment: What does it mean "user doesn't enter a message"? (And, how does the user enter messages? From the terminal?)  If something is waiting for user's message ... it'll wait. How would you abort on something that doesn't happen? A time-out?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you are unintentionally creating two children. Replace

```
if ($pid = fork)
```

with

```
if ($pid)
```

---

In the child, call

```
close(PIPE_WRITE);
```

In the parent, call

```
close(PIPE_READ);
```

In the parent (when done writing), call

```
close(PIPE_WRITE);
```

---

As for reading from a file handle until EOF or a specific command is entered,

```
while (my $line = <>) {
   last if $line =~ /^(?:quit|exit)$/;
   ...
}
```

Comment: Huh, replace `my $line = <FH>;` with `while (my $line = <FH>) { ... }`

Comment: Wherever you want to read lines from a file handle in a loop. [I'm confused. You know what `fork` is, but you don't know how to read from a file handle?]

Comment: Yes,  you could do that instead of what I suggested (though you'd have to add a `my` inside the `if` condition).

Comment: Use `$$` to get the current process's PID

Comment: That makes no sense. You mean until the user *won't* enter another message.  How do you know when that is? Usually, the user would signal EOF (which I already showed you how to handle already), or the user would type in a specific command (`quit` or `exit`) that indicates his wish to exit (`last if $line =~ /^(?:quit|exit)$/;`).